# Wix.com query. Filtering multiple categories script errror

Tags: javascript, html, web, velo

I´m building a wix.com page with wix.com code which should show some products.
There are 3 dropdown menus on the page which are already working and 13 categories to click on. After being clicked a var turns true etc. With a maximum of 3 selected the product should be filtered to the selected categories, only showing the products the 3 categories apply on.

I´m getting an "Script error" when I click the filtering button having nothing selected. It only works when both "Picto5" and "Picto10" are true.(Showing all items that have one of the categories.. :/)

export function FilterButton_click(event) {

```
//Pictogramme
var PictoFilter5 = (Picto5 === true)
? "Pictogramm5": undefined;
console.log(PictoFilter5);

var PictoFilter10 = (Picto10 === true)
? "Pictogramm10": undefined;
console.log(PictoFilter10);



//Dropdowns
var emotionValue = ($w('#EmotionDropdown').value !== "alle")
? $w('#EmotionDropdown').value
     : undefined;

var kategorieValue = ($w('#KategorieDropdown').value !== "alle") 
? $w('#KategorieDropdown').value 
    : undefined;

var dekoValue = ($w('#DekoDropdown').value !== "alle")
? $w('#DekoDropdown').value
     : undefined;

//Query
wixData.query("Steine")
    //Dropdowns
    .eq('grosse1', kategorieValue)
    .eq('pictogramm1', emotionValue)
    .eq('symbolSerieName', dekoValue)

    //Pictogramme
    .contains("kategorie1Sortierung", PictoFilter5)
    .contains("kategorie1Sortierung", PictoFilter10)

    .find()
    .then (res => {
            $w('#repeater1').data =res.items;
            console.log("Filtered to " + kategorieValue +" "+ dekoValue +" "+PictoFilter5+" "+PictoFilter10);
    })
     .catch( (error) => {
let errorMsg = error.message;
let code = error.code;
```

} );
}

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code you write you have the value true or false in the PictoFilter5 and PictoFilter10? If that is so you won't be able to use .contains to check that fields. You will need to have .eq to check a boolean field.

```
wixData.query("Steine")
.eq('grosse1', kategorieValue)
.eq('pictogramm1', emotionValue)
.eq('symbolSerieName', dekoValue)

//Pictogramme
.contains("kategorie1Sortierung", PictoFilter5)
.contains("kategorie1Sortierung", PictoFilter10)

.find()
```